# Tomcat error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem with eclipse that says the ports are already in use (80, 8009), When I change the ports I receive an error: Tomcat v6 at localhost failed to start.

When I debug Tomcat I receive this error:

```
11-Mar-2011 21:11:40 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;C:\Users\Rajin\Desktop\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse;
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:EducationGamesApp' did not find a matching property.
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 635 ms
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8008
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/29  config=null
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 390 ms
11-Mar-2011 21:11:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like its complaining on port 8005. Have you checked that?

Comment: I tried changing it but I still get the same error. When I try to start the port manually within properties it says port 8009 is already in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out which application hold the port(s) by running

- Windows: `netstat -no`
- Linux: `netstat -anp`

Look for `8005`, `8080`, `8009` ports listening on either `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`. Lookup the PID (process id) in Task Manager (Windows) or `ps` (Linux) to find out which program it is, terminate it, and try starting Tomcat again.

Comment: Most likely it's not so difficult by the way. It should be just another Tomcat running somewhere (another Eclipse or just as an already started instance).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. This worked when I restarted my laptop. Sorry :)

Comment: Please see mindas' answer to find out why exactly these ports.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Tomcat is using two ports: one for HTTP connector and one as "Server" port. If you open `tomcat/conf/server.xml`, you will see these ports defined:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  ...
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...
    ...
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" ...
  </Service>
</Server>
```

As you can see, port 8009 is used for AJP connector and 8080 for HTTP connector.

You need to ensure none of these three ports are being used by your system (another Tomcat or just another application) and if they are, you need to change these values to something else.

Answer (score 4):

download TCP view sw from the following link and unzip it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx.  see in the localport column is there any process worked in 8080 port . right click and end the process. then try to start the TomCat server. its really worked for me..

Comment: this is a very good solution for all those who are not very friendly with the cmd line. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause of this issue was the host file presented at WINDOWS_INSTALLTION/windows/System32/drivers/etc, where in which your old IP address was mapped against localhost like below:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 192.168.XXX.XX localhost

This second line was the main culprit, there are two ways of solving this:

- Remove 192.168.XXX.XX localhost line completely from host file
- Replace old IP with new IP in your host file i.e instead of 192.168.XXX.XX localhost change it to 192.168.XXX.YY localhost

Refer this blog for more details:
http://mprabhat.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/tomcat-java-net-bindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm_bind/

Answer (score 0):

No Circus,

1.Simply download this "apr-1.5.1-win32-src.zip" from https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi

2. Extract the folder
3. place it in the folder, that is in reach of Tomcat, in you case(C:\Users\Rajin\Desktop\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse).
4. Re-run the application/ restart the server.