# How to run servlet in eclipse juno?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

While i am trying to execute servlet program i got following error. please help me how to resolve this error? 
I tried many site but i can't clear the error. I think i did wrong while setting environment variable. I have installed jdk1.7.0_45 and apache tomcat7.0.47.

```
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;.;D:\Amutha\softwares\eclipse;;.
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yt' did not find a matching property.
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 716 ms
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 665 ms
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;.;D:\Amutha\softwares\eclipse;;.
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yt' did not find a matching property.
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 716 ms
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2013 12:11:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 665 ms
```

Comment: your error is similar to this one [same error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278442/tomcat-error-in-eclipse

Comment: i refered but stil i couldn't clear.